# Using google-signin without metadata tags

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to use the google signin lib without the metadata tags. (explanation for this at the end)

I largely seem to have this working but when my page loads I get an uncaught exception:

> Missing required parameter 'client_id'

The auth lib is obviously still trying to initialise despite me not specifying the client id in the metadata.

Is there any way of turning the lib off so that it does attempt the initialise until I call the [gapi.auth2.init](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initwzxhzdk20paramswzxhzdk21) function?

#### Why I don't want to use metadata tags

I have the example from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) working great but I want to incorporate this lib into my angular app that uses an angular service to sign in. I want my angular service to control when the lib is initialised, when it signs in and deal with the results. The example using metadata tags is great but seems to do everything itself without giving me much control.
For example, I want a loading state as the lib is initialising and logging in, I do not want to show a login button until this initial state has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading Google Sign-In button using declarative approach along with a framework tend to be a problem. I recommend you to try imperative approach.

I imagine you have

```
<div class="g-signin2"></div>
```

and

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

What you should do is:

1. Remove `.g-signin2` and specify an id. Because the library auto-detects the `g-signin2` and tries to replace it with a button widget.
2. Using JavaScript, bind a function to the button which invokes a manual sign-in.
3. Do manual initialization when you feel comfortable (for example, after the framework is completely loaded). The client id can be included as part of `auth2.init()` params.

You can find details here.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

FWIW, you can use `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` instead of `platform.js`. `platform.js` is for when you want to use widgets.

Comment: Are there docs for https://apis.google.com/js/api.js? It only seems to have one method on it - load. I can't call auth2.init() when I use that library.

As I mentioned in my other question if I remove the g-signin2 from the button div then the lib fails to load properly and I can't initialise it with gapi.auth2.init - I get cannot read property init of undefined

Comment: OK, I have got this working based on the example that you posted so I am accepting this as an answer (with some edits) but it has created a new problem - I cannot use getAuthInstance immediately to then call then to get informed of when init is complete - I'll create a new question.

Comment: api.js is platform.js without widget features. So they are basically identical except api.js lacks `.signin2` namespace. You will get `auth2` namespace once `gapi.load('auth2')` finish loading.