# How do I use GoogleAuth.then() when using google-signin without a class="g-signin2" div

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983283/using-google-signin-without-metadata-tags) I have this code that uses google sign in without using a div with the `g-signin2` style:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="APP_CLIENT_ID">
</head>
<body>
  <div  id="my-signin2"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
  <script>
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
      console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }

    function signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I want to use `GoogleAuth.then(onInit, onFailure)` so that I am informed of when the lib initialisation is complete and I can decide to update my view. I also can't add any listeners to be informed of when login has completed.

The problem is that `gapi.auth2` is undefined until a button has been created with the above code or with the class reference. It seems that without either of these 2 steps I can't call `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()` to setup listeners or get a promise informing me of when init is complete.

My problem is that I want to initialise before creating a button to see if I need to create a login button or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is answered by my other question in a similar area: [How do I initialise Google Sign in with no login button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983551/how-do-i-initialise-google-sign-in-with-no-login-button)

The answer is to not use platform.js but instead use api.js and load auth2:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            console.log( "signedin");
            // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        };

        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ID",
                scope: "profile email" // this isn't required
            }).then(function(auth2) {
                console.log( "signed in: " + auth2.isSignedIn.get() );  
                auth2.isSignedIn.listen(onSignIn);
                var button = document.querySelector('#signInButton');
                button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                  auth2.signIn();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="signInButton"><img src="IMAGE_FILE" /></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `gapi.auth2` you first need to load it.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  // continuation
  gapi.auth2.init();
});
```

platform.js basically loads api.js + `.signin2` namespace. `.signin2` namespace lets you render buttons and widgets. But if you want fine grained control, I wouldn't recommend you to use it.

What `.signin2` does is

- detect a class `g-signin2` and render a button
- render a button on a specified element
- invoke sign-in when clicked
- render the button with string depending on user's sign-in status